# Play Framework Guice Dependency Injection ProvisionError

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, bouncycastle

I have a class that is constructed like this

```
class CryptoManager @Inject()(config: Configuration) {

  Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())

  //Static values for Public Key Encryption
  private val pubkf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC")
  private val cspec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp192r1")
  private val privkeyString = config.getString("crypto.ECDSA.privkey").get
  private val r = new BigInteger(privkeyString, 16)
  private val ec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(r, cspec)
  private val privKey = pubkf.generatePrivate(ec)
...
}
```

When I build this explicitly in a test, it works fine:

```
   val config = Configuration.from(Map(
      "crypto" -> Map(
        "ECDSA" -> Map(
          "privkey" -> "b005ec459ad9482997757093df4c70732452083529617227",
          "pubkey" -> "04a4ec3b4e144434283a28c129ad5f2c13effc8dca6c79987bb8298c9be41e9c2f2176c9cacb2da156a095e68383a9f053",
          "bitlength" -> 192),
        "AES" -> Map(
          "secretkey" -> "ee21affe373c6e0e324fee2c0a6060e"
        ),
        "AESMAC" -> Map(
          "secretkey" -> "b9d1c0381f0ac08b27dcb945ff48c533"
        ))))

    val cryptoManager = new CryptoManager(config)
```

But when I try to inject an instance of this class into another class's constructor using Guice, I get the following error

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: key spec not recognized
  at com.nexkey.managers.CryptoManager.<init>(CryptoManager.scala:117)
  while locating com.nexkey.managers.CryptoManager
    for parameter 1 at com.nexkey.controllers.MessageController.<init>(MessageController.scala:23)
  at com.nexkey.controllers.MessageController.class(MessageController.scala:23)
  while locating com.nexkey.controllers.MessageController
    for parameter 7 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:51)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
```

I confirm that the values in my application's `application.conf` file are identical to the values in the config object I build in my test file. I also confirm that the value in `privkeyString` is identical in both cases.

I notice that if I supply the configuration as follows instead of injecting it, everything works:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.defaultApplication()
val conf = Configuration(config)
```

But I understand that this is the "wrong" way to do it and I'd prefer to figure out why Guice is failing to build my class.